# UFT Actions Issue

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to parameterize the actions and below is the code which I had designed

```
Datatable.ImportSheet "Q:\Excel.xls","Sheet1","Action1"
a=datatable.GetSheet("Action1").GetRowCount
For i= 1 to a 
Datatable.GetShee("Action1").SetCurrentRow(i)
If datatable.Value("OracleDatabase","Action1")<>"" Then
    RunAction Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1"), oneIteration,"Oracle"
    msgbox  Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1")
End If 
If datatable.Value("SQLdatabase","Action1")<>"" Then 
    RunAction Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1"), oneIteration 
    msgbox Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1") 
End If 
RunAction "Action1 [MediumSanityWF12]", oneIteration 
Next
```

The problem here is, when I was running the above code , for the first iteration "Action1 [GUITest1]" is being executed and it is correct.
 In the second iteration, for oracle database,"Action1 [GUITest2]" script executed and for SQL database again "Action1 [GUITest1]" got executed. As per my understanding it should execute "Action1 [GUITest2]" action only as I used the setcurrentrow method of datatable.
 I little confused here why it is executing the "Action1" for SQL database instead of "Action2" in the second iteration?

Please make me clear on this.

Comment: Share your data table

Comment: @Saikrishna: I am trying to paste the entire datatable but it just showing like below  Scriptname OracleDatabase SQLdatabase Access
Action1 [GUITest1] Yes Yes 
Action1 [GUITest2] YEs Yes

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work

```
Datatable.ImportSheet "Q:\Excel.xls","Sheet1","Action1"
a=datatable.GetSheet("Action1").GetRowCount
For i= 1 to a 
Datatable.GetSheet("Action1").SetCurrentRow(i)
If datatable.Value("OracleDatabase","Action1")<>"" Then
    RunAction Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1"), oneIteration,"Oracle"

End If 
Datatable.GetSheet("Action1").SetCurrentRow(i)
If datatable.Value("SQLdatabase","Action1")<>"" Then 
    RunAction Datatable.Value("Scriptname","Action1"), oneIteration 

End If 
RunAction "Action1 [MediumSanityWF12]", oneIteration 
Next
```

Comment: Yes, that's great. But my question here is,  why it is not working when I mention Setcurrentrow method only one time? .Actually it should set that particular row when I use the setcurrentrow method and it should take only values in that row only.But here what is happening is,for the first iteration, it is executing 'Action1' for both Oracle and SQL and for the second iteration, for Oracle database it is executing "Action2" and for SQL database it is going back and executing "Action1".This is not original behaviour of setcurrentrow method.I need the reason  why It is behaving like this.

Comment: Datatable is single object reference to the whole test .If you navigate to the next test action the getcurrent row will fetch the value for that test .so you need to get the current action sheet and set the current row value

Comment: Ok but If we put some text box related code instead of actions in above code setcurrentrow working fine and for every statement no need to put setcurrentrow  statement before the executable code. This is happening only when parameterizing actions.

Comment: The SetCurrentRow call is "undone" upon an action´s return: Beginning with QTP 11 (I think), returning from an action leads to the caller´s current row being reset to the iteration row. That´s why re-setting Action1´s current row after the RunAction call helps. That´s undocumented, unfortunately.